# Sort processes by start time

Tags: process, top, htop

Is there a way to view processes by the time they were started?  `top` and `htop` have an option for sorting by how much time a process has been running, but I would like to sort by when the process began (most recent on top).

Comment: How accurate does this have to be, using ps you can get it in hours/minutes for the current day, but older processes just say what date they started

Comment: @123, I am trying to get some information about a process that pops up only very briefly when I press a button in another program.  I want to list programs in `ps`, `top`, etc by start time so I can catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using htop 2.2.0. Please [try](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html):

```
htop --delay=3 --sort-key=STARTTIME
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this

```
while sleep 1;do ps -eo start_time,pid,euser,args:100 --sort start_time;done
```

This will list all processes running in order of start time although it will be latest at the bottom.
The loop update every second, if you need a finer time period change the sleep as needed.

If you want the latest at the top you can pipe into tac

```
while sleep 1;do ps -eo start_time,pid,euser,args:100 --sort start_time | tac ;done
```

This will reverse the order.

From the comment above though i don't think listing in order of start time is what you really want.If you know the name of the process beforehand then you can use

```
while sleep 0.1;do ps -eo start_time,pid,euser,args:100 | grep YOURCOMMAND;done
```

To just check for that single commands start time and output nothing if it is not running.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `watch` command for looping. http://www.linfo.org/watch.html